# How to call C# methods in C project

Tags: c#, c

I have a solution with 2 projects:
C# prj which is 64bit compiled
C prj 32bit

The main function should be in C project but I need to call a method that is in C# prj
Is there a way to do that?

I tried with the exemple posted here (dllExport) but nothing to do...
Many thx,
Marco

Comment: AFAIK they should be at least compiled in the same architecure.

Comment: You can't directly call functions in a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit DLL (and vice-versa), even if they are both written in the same language. You will need to use something like RPC to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the C# project a console application, then on your main project redirect the output and input of the C# console to the C project (might need to be async) after that you can call and hide the console prompt from your original project and send inputs + send outputs!

C# Example (C# running a C++ Console Prompt):

```
string Path = "C:\\Users\\noobz\\Desktop\\Task_1\\c.exe";
        char[] buffer = new char[100];
        string final = "NotFound";

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; // <--- You might want to edit this line

        do
        {
            proc.Start();
            final = GenerateString();
            proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(final);
            await proc.StandardOutput.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 100);
            Console.WriteLine(final);
        }
        while (buffer[29] == 'I');
```

Comment: 1) It is vice versa - OP needs to call C# dll from C 2) not all dlls can be conveniently turned into apps, not to mention potential performance hit.